# Issues with Devise Rememberable - No automatic logout on browser close

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, remember-me

So I am having trouble with the rememberable module for devise. I have all the setup implemented correctly: I added :rememberable to my user model, added the remember_created_at to the users table, and added the :remember_me checkbox on the login page.

I can confirm that if a user logs in without checking the remember me checkbox, that a cookie is created, the expiration is now, and the remember_created_at field is set to null. And if a user checks the checkbox a timestamp is saved in the remember_created_at field and the expiration date of the cookie is set to the default 2 weeks.

So the issues I am having:

1. If I don't check the remember me checkbox and login, close the browser, and then go back to the app I am still logged in. Isn't the idea if a user does not want to be remembered that when the browser is closed the session is destroyed? Or am I misunderstanding this?
2. For testing purposed I changed the :remember_for option to `1.minute`. So I checked the remember me box before logging in and verified the cookie expiration date is correct and a timestamp was saved in remember_created_at. I then closed the browser and waited about 2 minutes. I then opened the browser again and I was still logged in. Am I missing something or am I just not understanding the rememberable module correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: I was just looking more into the timestamp saved in the remember_created_at column. The timestamp is being saved in UTC, so in this example it is 2013-05-29 14:56:10.277, but I am in New england so the time is 10:56. And the server that is running the app is in Texas which is central time. I'm assuming that devise handles this (converting to/from UTC)? Or maybe this is why I am having problem with rememberable?

Comment: Where are you changing the `:remember_for` option, in `config/initializers/devise.rb`? If so, you have to restart the rails server for the configurations to take effect.

Comment: Yes, I set `:remember_for` in `config/initializers/devise.rb`. And yes I did restart the server several times.

Comment: I also want to note that I am using Devise 2.2.4

Comment: Could it be a cookie issue? Like I said previously the expiration for the cookie was set properly. However I am noticing that when I close the browser, wait the appropriate time, and then go back to the app the cookie (user_remember_token) is still there even though it is past the expiration timestamp.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this problem? I am also having the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was me not the devise gem. When I was testing I was closing a browser tab, not the entire browser.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issues with Devise Rememberable until I found out that Chrome doesn't expire the session cookies on "Browsing session end" after closing the browser when the option "On startup" - "Continue where I left off" is enabled in the Settings.

Comment: Chrome's default behavior was the issue for me as well. Testing this in FF verified that Devise was working as intended. Typically I would use Chrome's Incongito windows to test sessions but that obviously doesn't work to verify that Devise "does not remember' me.

Comment: Same issue here with chrome.  Wish I had seen this earlier before spending all that time trying to figure it out.